# limit dropzone to single file

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I have dropzone and I want to limit it to only one file, how can I achive that?

here my code:

```
<form action="Options.html" class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="mydropzone">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop file here</span><br /></div>
</form>
```

I tried like:

```
$('#mydropzone')[0].dropzone = {
   maxFiles: 1
};
```

[The doc](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting the class of dropzone on your form it is using the default settings to instantiate the dropzone, which means when you get to your code it sees the dropzone has already been created and ignores your code.

I'd recommend either removing the dropzone class from your form (since your code will instantiate the object) or you can change the default settings by using the format below:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropZone = {
//myDropZone is the camelized version of the elements ID
maxFiles: 1,
}
```

See [here](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration) for more details.